# Help solving kirchhoff's law for two voltage sources and two resistors in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: Circuit with voltage source, resistor (two times) in series]

I need to find the voltage drop between R1 (4 Ohm) and R2 (2 Ohm). 
I tried applying Kirchhoff's law in this way:
\$-10+4I-8-2I=0\$ and then solving by \$I\$ I have \$I=9 A\$ but that's not correct. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is total voltage?  What is total resistance?

Answer (score 3):

Why did you change the sign for the voltage sources and for the resistor drops?  Imagine first there was only one source and one resistor (R10).  You would have +10 - 4I = 0.

Now add the second resistor, you get +10 - 4I - 2I = 0.  If you aren't comfortable with that, imagine first combining both resistors into one, it would be 6 Ohms, right?  So you would have +10 - 6I = 0, which is the same as above.

Per KVL, the order of the the components doesn't matter, so you can apply the same logic to the sources.  A 10V and 8V source in series and in the same polarity produce a 18V source.  Don't be fooled by the fact the 8V source is on the right side of the circuit, upside-down; it's still adds to the total voltage source.  So you would have +10 + 8 -4I - 2I = 18 - 6I = 0

You might find it easier to rearrange the drawing like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fecObf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Remember though this doesn't hold once you add any parallel item or branched circuit.